# How to insert items to a jcombobox at runtime and save it

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox, comboboxmodel

I need to save the values in my jcombobox at the runtime. What I am trying to do is after clicking on a button, I am setting it to editable = true. Then type the value in the combobox, but it doesn't save.

```
private void btadbknameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  if(evt.getSource()== btadbkname){
    cb_bkname.setEditable(true);
    cb_bkname.getText();
    cb_bkname.addItem(evt);
  }else{
    cb_bkname.setEditable(false);
  }
}
```

I have already added some elements in it on the designing level, but it's limited if some random value comes then its a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't save"? Do you mean that you're not seeing the ActionEvent.toString() representation in the combobox? Or that you are seeing a new item in the JComboBox, but it doesn't persist if you close the program and then re-open it?

Comment: no at the runtime if i enter some random value other than what i have set previously then that is not adding in the combobox list. i need to add some value to the combobox list when i click on the button. i dont have much knowledge of progrmaing what i know i have tried but it dosent work

Comment: I second the recommendation that you will want to review your previous questions and accept more of them -- we greatly appreciate that, but I'm not sure how we can help based on such limited information. Consider creating and posting a small compilable and runnable program (please no NetBeans-generated code) that demonstrates your problem, and I'll bet we can help better, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Note that JComboBoxes don't even have a `getText()` method, so if cb_bkname is your JComboBox, I'm surprised if this code even compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Because it is possible to `add` / `remove Item`(s) to / from the `DefaultComboBoxModel` underlaying the `JComboBox`, the same action (by default) is possible from outside.
- You have to use [`MutableComboBoxMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/MutableComboBoxModel.html) to `add` / `remove Item`(s) to / from `JComboBox` that fires event from itself (view_to_model).
- There are excellent examples of `MutableComboBoxModel` by `@Robin` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12508002/714968) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10203745/714968).
- [For better help sooner post an SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), for future readers, otherwise search for `extends AbstractListModel implements MutableComboBoxModel`.

Answer (score 1):

it can't possibly work the way you're trying it.

the comboBox has to be editable before you click the button then you just need this line

```
cb_bkname.addItem(((JTextField)cb_bkname.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void btadbknameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      if(evt.getSource()== btadbkname){
        cb_bkname.setEditable(true);
        String newItem=cb_bkname.getText();
        cb_bkname.addItem(newItem);
      }else{
        cb_bkname.setEditable(false);
      }
    }
```