# Update JComboBox popupMenu

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` with only one value in the start and have one MouseListener connected to it. When I click on the `JComboBox` I fill it with some new values. But the popupMenu are of the size of one element on the first click on the `JComboBox`. The second time all values will appear as normal. 
Any idea how I can make the comboBox update its popupMenu directly after I have updated its content?

Example program:

```
public class ComboBoxUpdate extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    private JComboBox<String> box;
    public ComboBoxUpdate(){
        // Init
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        box = new JComboBox<String>();
        box.addItem("from start");

        // Add listener
        Component[] comps = box.getComponents();
        for(int i = 0; i < comps.length; i++)
            comps[i].addMouseListener(this);

        panel.add(box);
        this.add(panel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(box.getItemCount() == 1){
            box.removeAllItems();
            box.addItem("item 1");
            box.addItem("item 2");
            box.addItem("item 3");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ComboBoxUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the better solution:

```
public class ComboBoxUpdate extends JFrame implements PopupMenuListener {

    private JComboBox box;

    public ComboBoxUpdate() {
        // Init
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        box = new JComboBox();
        box.addItem("from start");

        box.addPopupMenuListener(this);

        panel.add(box);
        this.add(panel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        if (box.getItemCount() == 1) {
            box.removeAllItems();
            box.addItem("item 1");
            box.addItem("item 2");
            box.addItem("item 3");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes my box only flash-and-close on first click.
How it works: The list displays "Choose car" from start. When clicked only cars should show up.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a JComboBox with only one value in the start and have one
>   MouseListener connected to it. When I click on the JComboBox I fill it
>   with some new values

1. `Item`(s) to `JComboBox` on runtime could be add/remove/modify into `XxxComboBoxModel` only
2. use [DefaultComboBoxModel](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:714968%20%5Bjcombobox%5D%20defaultcomboboxmodel) in the case that you'll change all Items
3. use [MutableComboBoxModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14309338/714968) for add/remove/modify Item(s) on runtime

Comment: Tried this but still same result:
`code`@Override
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  if(box.getItemCount() == 1){
   String[] newData = {"item1","item2","item3"};
   DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel( newData );
            box.setModel( model );
  }
 }`code`

Answer (score 0):

Try `mousePressed()` or `mouseReleased()` events instead of `mouseClicked()` event. Also you have to `repaint()` to make the changes visible.

```
       @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Pressed");
             if(box.getItemCount() == 1){
                 box.removeAllItems();
                 box.addItem("item 1");
                 box.addItem("item 2");
                 box.addItem("item 3");
                 repaint();
             }
        }
```

Comment: Moved to mousePressed and added repaint() but still same result.