# how to add elements in jcombobox dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, comboboxmodel

```
jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
```

I want to know ,how to add elements in the comboBox at the run-time?

Comment: this might be able to help: http://bit.ly/1g5kmzH

Comment: @failed.down and then this page comes up .... :D

Answer (score 5):

> "I want to know ,how to add elements in the comboBox at the run-time?"

See [`DefaultComboBoxModel#addElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html#addElement%28E%29)

- `public void addElement(E anObject)`

**Description copied from interface: `MutableComboBoxModel`**
Adds an item at the end of the model. The implementation of this method should notify all registered ListDataListeners that the item has been added.

In your case, since you have no reference to the model, you need to do this

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel)jComboBox2.getModel();
model.addElement(...)
```

---

And see [How to Use ComboBoxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

---

Also learn to read the Documentation. Just go [**Here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/) and you could've searched `DefaultComboBoxModel` or any other class you are unfamiliar with.

Comment: Also check the tutorial here --> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Comment: +1 note == for add Items at runtime is better to use MutableComboBoxModel, as is suggested in answer by @developer known as Insar (+1)

Comment: this solution throws an unchecked warning

Answer (score 1):

I guess that [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507926/add-items-runtime-on-combobox-in-java) would help for you.

i copied this from that answer.

If your combobox has a `MutableComboBoxModel`, you can do the following

```
MutableComboBoxModel model = (MutableComboBoxModel)combo.getModel();
model.addElement( elementToAdd );
```

This is equivalent to calling `JComboBox#addItem` (see below for the implementation):

```
public void addItem(Object anObject) {
    checkMutableComboBoxModel();
    ((MutableComboBoxModel)dataModel).addElement(anObject);
}
```

But I think it is a best practice to modify the model directly if you want to make changes on the model side, and not go through the view (except to provide the user the ability to edit in the view)